# Given $\lvert \vec u \rvert, \lvert \vec v \rvert$, and $\angle(\vec u, \vec v)$, calculate $\cos \angle(\vec u + \vec v, \vec u - \vec v)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

If $\measuredangle(\vec u,\vec v)=\frac{\pi}{6}$, $|\vec u|=\sqrt 3$, $|\vec v|=1$, calculate $\cos \measuredangle (\vec u + \vec v,\vec u - \vec v)$.

I posted this question with incorrectly typing, now it's correct. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Methodology Answer**

Here's what you need to know:
$$\cos (x,y) = \frac{x \cdot y}{|x||y|},$$
and the dot product is linear in its arguments. You may find it helpful to note that $|x| = \sqrt{x \cdot x}$. So write what you need in terms of dot products, distribute where you can, and if you multiply enough things out and hit it with a sufficiently large algebra hammer, you'll get your answer.